# 'Cannot find package' importing file (ts-node-esm)

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I am new to TypeScript and have started to rewrite one of my Discord bots using TS. However, I am running into an issue when I am trying to import another TS file containing a function.
My bot is of `"type": "module",` (ESM) and this is inside of the `package.json`.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    "module": "es2020",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "src",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/Utils/*": ["Utils/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    "outDir": "./build",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": ["build", "node_modules"],
}
```

`Util.ts`:

```
export function deletableCheck() {
    return 'example'
}
```

`Ping.ts`:

```
import { deletableCheck } from "@/Utils/Util";
```

When I try to start my bot with `ts-node-esm src/Main.ts`, I get the error:

```bash
CustomError: Cannot find package '@/Utils' imported from /Users/ragnarlothbrok/IdeaProjects/TheSeer-TSRewrite/src/Commands/Miscellaneous/Ping.ts
```

I have tried writing it as

```
import { deletableCheck } from "../../Utils/Util";
```

but I receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare your alias like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@/Utils/*": ["./Utils/*"]
    },
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: With this change, the error changes to: "src/Commands/Miscellaneous/Ping.ts:6:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/Utils/Util' or its corresponding type declarations."

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realise you had `src` already as your base URL. I've provided an update that should work now. Take a look at [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tyesus?file=src/Commands/Miscellaneous/Ping.ts) proving it to work.

Comment: You put the import in a file that is never executed. I moved it to counter.ts and it logged:
"The following dependencies are imported but could not be resolved:
 @/Utils/Util (imported by /home/projects/vitejs-vite-ge3ogq/src/counter.ts)"

Comment: Please, could you create a replica of your setup? I'm having a hard time to replicate it myself (to begin with, you didn't even provide the paths for the files you posted, I had to guess them from the error message). I'm starting to suspect your error might not be coming from typescript but other compilation tools like Vite. Do you use Vite or similar?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I start the Discord bot with `ts-node-esm src/Main.ts`, never heard of Vite

Comment: Here, it is impossible to miss the [error now](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qlgeeh?file=src/counter.ts)

Comment: And here it is [the solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-uxrnzo?file=vite.config.js) (take a look at the contents of `vite.config.js`). But again, the error you see on your link is because Vite does not find the module so you just need to provide the resolve path for Vite. Any typescript error you had, should be cleared with the solution I posted in the answer. If this still does not solve it, I can only suggest for you to push the code (stripping it from sensitive information) into a github repo for me to take a look at.

Comment: I have [uploaded to github](https://github.com/RagnarLothbrok-Odin/TheSeer-Discord/tree/temp) Please ensure you are on the `temp` branch. Rename `.env.example` to `.env` and input a bot token. Install dependencies and run the `dev` script you see in the `package.json`

Comment: Right, I see your point now (soz!). I have to be honest, I never managed to get `ts-node-esm` to work correctly for me. However, I did some progress on your project. I believe `ts-node-esm` is just providing a sort of translation layer for an underlying `node` which means that the files must be `js` for `node` to pick them up. If you change the import `@/Utils/Util` in `Ping.ts` and replace it with `../../Utils/Util.js`, it works. It also does so if you compile the entire project first (`tsc`) and then run it (`node build/Main.js`). Unfortunately I still can't make it work with the `@` tho.

Comment: I know it looks like I'm trying to shove it down your throat at this point (sorry again for the confusion) but I think Vite solves precisely those problems very nicely (I'm currently working with it and I can't be happier). [Take a look at it](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) if you want.

Comment: Can you use Vite with a Discord bot? It looks more focused on web development

Comment: Yup. On my current project, I'm building a daemon-like software to sit behind a firewall with no I/O other than a message queue. Take a look at [this configuration](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode).